# Maven doesn't detect JAVA_HOME correctly on Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu-18.04

I was playing around with some environmental variables in Ubuntu 18.04.5, trying to make them not reset every time I re-open terminal.

However, now Maven is reacting to every command with this error:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

I'm pretty sure that my `$JAVA_HOME` points to the right directory, because command `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

And command  `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java --version` returns:

```
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Before this error, I've added this lines to `/etc/environment`:

```
export JAVA14="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14"
export JAVA11="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

And following lines to `~/.bashrc`:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Also, after some editing I've returned everything as it was before and command `sudo update-alternatives --config java` return the following:

```
  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64            1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
```

So the right path is selected, and also I have not changed any other `update-alternatives` configurations.

What can I do to make Maven see $JAVA_HOME again?

**EDIT:**

I've fixed this issue by directly editing the `/usr/share/maven/bin/mvn` script and hard-coding path to `java` executable into `JAVACMD` variable. However, I'm still interested in *normal* solution to this problem.

Comment: can you provide us the output of the command `mvn -version` which will display the Java_home that maven picks up during its process?

Comment: It displays the same error:
```The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE```

Comment: what do you get if you run "java -version" ?

Comment: Have you added to that JAVA_HOME to PATH?

Comment: Running ```java --version``` gives the same result as ```$JAVA_HOME/bin/java --version```.

Comment: Yes, it has been added to the path.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue...

Comment: @Thirumal I had to manually change it in my `mvn` script

Comment: @Covariance Can you add it in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have comment privileges yet (or I would make this hopefully helpful guess a comment) but you should check $HOME/.mvnrc (or the equivalent) to see if JAVA_HOME is being set there.